# there's a way to sort a regular expressions list by specificity?

Tags: regex, algorithm, theory, computation-theory

I'm looking for something that allows me to sort a list of regular expression,
or some documentation and research,

according to their specificity/strictness

```
/[a-z]+/           // most strict
/[a-z0-9]+/
/[a-z0-9èòà]+/     // less strict
/.*/
```

but how about

```
/[a-z]+ABC/
/[a-z0-9]+/
```

which one is less specific than the other?

thank you in advance

Comment: Ehm, no idea? More specific about what? How do you compare two regular expression? They are meant to match different things or?

Comment: You can define a specificity yourself: I would define it as follows: Regex1 is more specific than Regex2 iff all strings matched by Regex1 are also matched by Regex2 (i.e. if L(regex1) is a subset of L(regex2)). If neither of the subsets is a subset of the other, I would call them "incomparable".

Comment: @phimuemue ... which is the case of the second example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can equate a regular expression to the set of strings it matches (called a 'regular language'.)  If our regular expression is named `E`, let's call its matching strings `L(E)`.

Strictness in the sense you are alluding to above then becomes the subset relation: define RE `A` to be stricter than RE `B` if `L(A)` is a proper subset of `L(B)`.  This puts to rest ambiguities like synonyms for the "same" RE: they are the same precisely because they have the same regular language.

As @yi_H points out, the subset relation over RE languages (over some common alphabet) forms a partial ordering.  You sound like you want a total ordering.  If so, you can stipulate that an acceptable total ordering should embed the partial ordering represented by the subset relation.

I don't have a clear answer for how to build that total ordering, but two approaches come to mind.

The first is to exploit the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).  It turns out that for any RE, if it matches a sufficiently long string, then it must also match a longer string constructible from the first by repeating some subsection.  You could ask what is the length of the longest matching string that does not have any such repeating segments, and make that your metric.  Maybe that respects (embeds) the partial ordering, maybe it doesn't.

The other is to consider graph transformations on the RE's state machine.  I suspect (but I don't have any reference) that if RE `A` is properly stricter than RE `B`, then `B`'s automaton will be calculable from `A`'s by collapsing states or some similar simplifying action.  You could define your metric to be the number of states in the RE's smallest automaton.

Comment: There are a series of papers by Almeida and others, I believe, that use Brzozowski's notion of derivatives of regular expressions to perform efficient testing for equality and order of regular expressions. I think this would be a better solution for the OP, because nobody wants to implement the NDA/DFA/REGEXP algorithms.

Comment: Awesome, sounds like someone else has thought through this already.  Refs for the papers?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find the paper on inclusion that I was thinking of, but I believe Almeida's paper "Testing the Equivalence of Regular Languages" and Antimirov's paper "Rewriting Extended Regular Expressions" talk about testing equivalence and inclusion. I think the paper I was thinking of was titled "Partial Derivatives..." by Antimirov. There is a Haskell implementation called regexpr-symbolic on hackage.

Answer (score 2):

As your second example shows you cannot have a total ordering of regular expressions, only a [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) is possible.

To make things even worse, there are dozens of ways you can write the same regular expression:  `[ab]b` vs `(ab|bb)`, `aa*` vs `a+`. So even deciding whether two regexpes are [equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Deciding_equivalence_of_regular_expressions) is not a simple task.

Comment: Good comment, but this is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about pure regular expressions, rather than the crazy perl stuff, you can define a *partial* order on regular expressions that matches your question, based on the set of strings they accept (i.e., view the regular expression as a regular language).

Given that the difference, intersection, and emptiness of regular languages are decidable problems, that means there are algorithms that will tell you if one of your expressions accepts all the strings another one does.